# Prove that an infinite subset of positive integers is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$Let\  C\ be\ an\ infinite\ subset\ of\ \mathbb{Z}_+ $$

Then definite $$h: \mathbb{Z}_+ \rightarrow C $$

by $$h(n)=smallest\ element\ of\ [C-h(\{1,2,3,\dots ,n-1\})]$$

It is not hard to see why this is injective.

For surjection, in my book, it says that there exists smallest element m such that for any c in C  $$h(m)\geq c$$

$$Then\ for\ all\ i<m, we\ must\ have\ h(i)<c$$

here I do not understand why

Since $h(m)$ is the smallest element of $C-\{h(1),h(2),h(3)...h(m-1)\}$, if $h(m)>c$, shouldn't it follow that $c \in \{h(1),h(2),h(3)...h(m-1)\}$?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see that $h$ is surjective is by definition. We must show that for any $c \in C$ there exists $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $h(n) = c$. To this end, let $c \in C$. Notice that $C$ can be well ordered and $C$ inherits it's well ordering from $\mathbb{Z}_+$. Therefore, every non empty subset of $C$ has a smallest element. Now, choose $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $c$ is the least element of $C - \{h(1) \dots h(n - 1)\}$. Now by definition of $h$, $h(n) = c$. Thus, $h$ is a surjection.

Comment: One nit-picky thing: We are not just choosing any well-ordering for $C$. $C$ inherits it's well ordered from $\mathbb{Z}_+$. Alternatively, $\mathbb{Z}_+$ induces a well-ordering on $C$ and that's why the function works. Also, shouldn't it read $C - \{h(1),...,h(n-1)\}$ instead of $C - \{h(n),...,h(n-1)\}$?

Comment: You are correct, I've edited my answer to reflect your comment